# Numpy + OpenCV-Python : Get coordinates of white pixels

Tags: numpy, opencv, python

I have a grayscale image and I want to get all the coordinates of pixels with intensity level 255.

I tried using:

```
pixels = np.where(img[img == 255])
```

But instead of getting a list of (X,Y) coordinates, I got a list of numbers, like if `img` was a one dimensional vector.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `np.argwhere(img == 255)`.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I'll be glad if you could please post it as an answer, so I can accept it

Comment: I believe it has already been covered in previous SO posts. Not an exact one, but a close one has been added as dupe.